# single-type.php not working, delivering 404

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, permalinks

I've created a custom post type, and have successfully added a few entries. I can call these entries out with `query_posts()` to show on the front page, but `the_permalink()` on each of them just sends me to a "Page not found" 404.

Am I missing something? I'm currently running on `http://localhost`, so the results of `the_permalink()` from the front page custom post type loop sends the user to `http://localhost/PU/PU2010/website/cartoons/einstein-on-california`.

#### functions.php

```
function createCartoonPostType() {
    register_post_type( 'cartoon', array(
        'label' => 'Cartoon',
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'cartoons' )
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'createCartoonPostType' );
```

According to this, I should be able to just create `single-cartoon.php`, correct?

#### single-cartoon.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="container_20">
        <div class="grid_14">
            <div class="bodybox">
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php the_title(); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_6">
            <?php get_template_part( 'social', 'box' ); ?>
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

#### loops-cartoons.php (frontpage loop)

```
<?php query_posts( 'post_type=cartoon&posts_per_page=1' ); ?>
<div class="cartoons-box">
    <ul class="cartoons-list">
    <?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?>
        Sorry, no posts.
    <?php else : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <li>
             <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="preview-image">
                   <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'featured' ); ?>
                 </a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Did you go to Admin -> Settings -> Permalinks after setting up the post type? The permalink structure hasn't been added until you've done that. It could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Weird...just have to open up that page and it fixed everything. @John please post this as the answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you go to Admin -> Settings -> Permalinks after setting up the post type? The permalink structure hasn't been added until you've done that. It could be the cause of your problem.

The permalinks page fires `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` each time the page is visited, so it's not even necessary to save.

Answer (score 9):

After registering the custom post types you need to rebuild permalinks. You can do that manually by visiting Admin -> Settings -> Permalinks (as John commented), you can rebuild permalinks within your code by calling `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` or if you're lazy you can make use of the [Permafrost (Wordpress Plugin)](http://codex.wordpress.org/User%3aHakre/permafrost).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - and every time I added a new page it required the permalinks structure reset. Adding this:

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

within your createCartoonPostType() function immediately after the register_post_type part solves the problem though and means you don't need to use the keep resetting permalinks.